# Sum of two random noises

Tags: power-spectral-density

Let $u_1$ be a random noise in $\mathbb R$. The PSD of $u_1$ is constant in the interval $[f_{1,1}; f_{1,2}]$ and is noted $p_1$.

Let $u_2$ be a random noise in $\mathbb R$. The PSD of $u_2$ is constant in the interval $[f_{2,1}; f_{2,2}]$ and is noted $p_2$.

The intervals $[f_{1,1}; f_{1,2}]$ and $[f_{2,1}; f_{2,2}]$ are disjoint.

Is the PSD of $u_1+u_2$ computable ? Does it only depends on $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the PSD of u1 and u2 computable ? Does it only depends on p1 and p2 ?

Yes. The Fourier Transform is a linear operation so the spectrum of the sum is simply the sum of the spectra. The PSD is just magnitude squared of the Fourrier Transform but since the frequency intervals are disjoint the squaring doesn't create any type of interaction between the two original spectral. So it's simply

$$P_{sum}(f) = \begin{cases}
 & p_1\text { if } f_{11} < f < f_{12} \\ 
 & p_2 \text{ if }  f_{21} < f < f_{22} \\
 & 0 \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases} $$

Comment: oh, wait... you're right

Comment: If it is as simple as that, which is what I initially though, then i must have a mistake in my MATLAB script ! 
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Actually, as long as the two noise processes are mutually orthogonal, the power spectral density of their sum is the sum of their power spectral densities.  This applies whether their PSD's are disjoint or not -- but having disjoint PSD's insures that they're mutually orthogonal.  (Note that if they're zero-mean and statistically independent they're mutually orthogonal, but not, for some oddball exceptions, the other way around).

Comment: @TimWescott that "oddball exception" would be for example if the two signals were the same, but with opposite signs... not that oddball! dependent processes happen all the time, and things like random phase fluctuations can make the expectation of point-wise product (i.e. the correlation) between easily zero in reality!

Comment: Two signals that are identical but of opposite sign aren't orthogonal -- they're 100% correlated!  I'm not sure what you're thinking, here.